Implementar uma função que dois conjuntos e sua relação, deve ser determinada se a relação é reflexiva, simétrica e transitiva
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 25
#define tam_conj 5

void leitura_conjuntos(int conjunto[], int num_conjunto);
void leitura_relacao(int[][2], int *num_pares);
int verificacao_reflexiva(int v1[], int v2[], int R[][2], int num_pares);
int verificacao_simetrica(int R[][2], int num_pares);
int verificacao_transitiva(int R[][2], int num_pares);

int main(){

int v1[tam_conj], v2[tam_conj], R[max][2], num_pares, i;

 leitura_conjuntos(v1, 1); //leitura do conjunto 1
 printf("\n");
 leitura_conjuntos(v2, 2); //leitura do conjunto 2

 leitura_relacao(R, &num_pares);

 // Verificação das propriedades
    if (verificacao_reflexiva(v1, v2, R, num_pares)) {
        printf("A relacao eh reflexiva.\n");
    } else {
        printf("A relacao nao eh reflexiva.\n");
    }

    if (verificacao_simetrica(R, num_pares)) {
        printf("A relacao eh simetrica.\n");
    } else {
        printf("A relacao nao eh simetrica.\n");
    }

    if (verificacao_transitiva(R, num_pares)) {
        printf("A relacao eh transitiva.\n");
    } else {
        printf("A relacao nao eh transitiva.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

//leitura dos dois conjuntos.
void leitura_conjuntos(int conjunto[], int num_conjunto){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<tam_conj; i++){
    printf("informe o valor %d do %d conjunto: \n", i+1, num_conjunto);
    scanf("%d", &conjunto[i]);
  }
}
// leitura do conjunto de relacao R.
void leitura_relacao(int R[][2], int *num_pares){
  int i;
  printf("informe o numero de pares (max %d): ", max);
  scanf("%d", num_pares);
  if (*num_pares > max) {
        printf("Erro: numero de pares excede o maximo permitido.\n");
        *num_pares = 0; //zera os num_pares para indicar erro
        return;
    }
  for(i=0; i < *num_pares; i++){
    printf("informe os pares ordenados (x,y): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &R[i][0], &R[i][1]); //o primeiro elemento R[i][0] e o segundo elemento R[i][1]
    }
}
//funcao para verificar se a relacao é reflexiva
int verificacao_reflexiva(int v1[], int v2[], int R[][2], int num_pares){
   int i, j, encontrado_v1, encontrado_v2;
   for(i=0; i<tam_conj; i++){
     encontrado_v1 = 0;
     for(j=0; j<num_pares; j++){
        if(v1[i] == R[j][0] && v1[i] == R[j][1]){
            encontrado_v1 = 1;
            break;
     }
   }
   if(!encontrado_v1) return 0;
   }
   for(i=0; i<tam_conj; i++){
     encontrado_v2 = 0;
     for(j=0; j<num_pares; j++){
        if(v2[i] == R[j][0] && v2[i] == R[j][1]){
            encontrado_v2 = 1;
            break;
     }
   }
  if(!encontrado_v2) return 1;
 }
 return 1;
}
//funcao para verificar se a relacao é simétrica.
int verificacao_simetrica(int R[][2], int num_pares){
 int i, j, encontrado;
 for(i=0; i<num_pares; i++){
     encontrado = 0;
     for(j=0; j<num_pares; j++){
        if(R[i][0] == R[j][1] && R[i][1] == R[j][0]){
            encontrado = 1;
            break;
     }
   }
  if(!encontrado) return 0;
 }
 return 1;
}
//funcao para verificar se a relacao é transitiva.
int verificacao_transitiva(int R[][2], int num_pares){
 int i, j, k, encontrado;
 for(i=0; i<num_pares; i++){
    for(j=0; j<num_pares; j++){
        if(R[i][1] == R[j][0]){
            encontrado = 0;
            for(k=0; k<num_pares; k++){
                if(R[k][0] == R[i][0] && R[k][1] == R[j][1]){
                    encontrado = 1;
                    break;
                }
           }
           if(!encontrado) return 0;
        }
    }
 }
 return 1;
}


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
